# Implement sorting in a ListView based on price (ascending and descending) and discount price

Tags: python, html, django

```
view.py
class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Item
    template_name = "home.html"
    paginate_by = 12

template
<div class="header-dropdown">
    <a href="#">A to Z</a>
        <div class="header-menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">A to Z</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Z to A</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Discount</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Low to high price</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">High to low price</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</div>
```

How can I get `queryset` for each list such that it reorders the list in different ways and display it in the template without reloading the page?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get_ordering` or `get_queryset` method to sort the data but to implement all this **without reloading the page** you need to use something like Ajax. In that case, to make this simple, I am going to tweak your code a little bit like using a regular function base view that returns a JSON response.

`views.py`

```py
from django.http import JsonResponse
from .models import Item # your item model

def item_list(request):
    sort_by = request.GET.get('sort_by', '-price')
    if sort_by == 'price_asc':
        queryset = Item.objects.order_by('price')
    elif sort_by == 'price_desc':
        queryset = Item.objects.order_by('-price')
    elif sort_by == 'discount_asc':
        queryset = Item.objects.order_by('discount_price')
    elif sort_by == 'discount_desc':
        queryset = Item.objects.order_by('-discount_price')
    else:
        queryset = Item.objects.order_by('-price')

    items = list(queryset.values())
    return JsonResponse({'products': items})
```

Here in the template, I created a form to control the sort functionality.

`your_template.html`

```html
<form id="sort-form">
    <select name="sort_by" id="sort-by">
        <option value="price_asc">Price Ascending</option>
        <option value="price_desc">Price Descending</option>
        <option value="discount_asc">Discount Ascending</option>
        <option value="discount_desc">Discount Descending</option>
    </select>
</form>

<div id="results">
    <!-- your product data will display here -->
</div>
```

To prevent page reloading use `ajax`. Here when you submit the form the page won't reload because of AJAX. AJAX will take your form data and send it to the Django view like a normal form but with no page reloading. Then Django will send a JSON response back with your data. Then we can display the data

```js
const sortSelect = document.getElementById('sort-by');
const sortForm = document.getElementById('sort-form');
const results = document.getElementById('results');

sortSelect.addEventListener('change', function () {
        const formData = new FormData(sortForm);
        fetch('replace_this_with_the_view_url', {
            method: 'GET',
            body: formData,
            headers: {
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
           }
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            const products = data.products;
            result.innerHTML = '';
            products .forEach(product => {
            const productDiv = document.createElement('div');
            productDiv.textContent = product.name; // replace with your data
            results.appendChild(productDiv);
        });        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        });
    });
```

This is my way of doing this but maybe there is a better or simple way of doing this. I hope this might help you

Comment: Very difficult for me to relate with this codes especially the javascriot. I am just trying to patch up. If you can do better explanation. it will help